# R Summarise Data based on logical index for multiple criteria including date difference

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset where I have a date in which a medication was ordered `RequestedDtm` and I want to get a specific datapoint `pc_before_rx` which is recorded at an `ObsDtm`

```
RxUnique %>%
  inner_join(PatientVS) %>%
  group_by(UniqueID, RequestedDtm) %>%
  arrange(UniqueID, ObsDtm)%>%
  summarise(
        pc_before_rx = last(ObsValue[ObsCatalogName == 'pc_recording' & difftime(RequestedDtm, ObsDtm, units = 'hours') < 24]), 
        dt_settings_before_rx = last(ObsDtm[ObsCatalogName == 'pc_recording' & difftime(RequestedDtm, ObsDtm, units = 'hours') < 24])) %>%
  mutate(time = difftime(dt_settings_before_rx, RequestedDtm, units = 'hours'))
```

Produces:

```
    UniqueID                    RequestedDtm        pc_before_rx dt_before_rx time            
   <chr>                       <dttm>                                        <dbl> <dttm>                 <drtn>          
 1 5936655 2020-05-02 11:03:38                              NA NA                             NA hours
 2 5925423 2020-04-23 06:01:43                              14 2020-05-01 23:26:00    209.404508 hours
 3 5917885 2020-04-12 16:35:53                              12 2020-05-08 23:55:00    631.318448 hours
 4 5930494 2020-05-01 10:36:54                              15 2020-05-05 00:00:00     85.384895 hours
```

Clearly, the logical index for getting the last result of that day prior to the `RequestedDtm` is not working. Is there any way to get this filter/logical index to work?

Comment: Please consider to show a small reproducible example

Comment: Well have you tried looking at your data to check that the values there arent `NA` in the original data?  I am asking this because it seems like it could take over a month for the `rx` date to be logged. So your NA probably still hasn't been logged in your data. have a look and let us know.

Comment: there are definitely some NA in the original data, not everyone in the dataset will have these settings